# Does Huawei Push Provide push token for test？

Tags: java, android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Does Huawei provide a spefic push token for mock test?
We want to leverage the spefic push token to make sure that the Huawei push service is working?

Comment: There is no specific token. And the token corresponds to the device, Only a real phone device can obtain a token. And btw why can't you obtain a real token?